# Topological implications of symbolic represenation of the relativity

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, topology, complex-numbers

I have seen in the online Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy in the entry on Copenhagen Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics that Niels Bohr had argued that [the theory of relativity is not a literal representation of the universe.](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-copenhagen/#Com)

By this he means that like the quantum mechanics, the theory of relativity involves $i$ in its equations. That is in the fourth dimension of spacetime. Therefore it is a symbolic not pictorial representation of the universe.

Now I am trying to make sense of the geometrical implications for the spacetime.

Consider a flat universe and dimensions in which $c=1$. The metric with the $-+++$ signature could be read like:

$i^2d\alpha^2+d\theta^2+d\phi^2+d\psi^2$

We can have the global spacetime topology defined by

$C_{\infty} \times C_{\infty} \times C_{\infty} \times C_{\infty}$

Where $C_{\infty}$ is the Riemann sphere.

Now the above local metric of a flat universe can be interpreted as describing a complex 4-torus or just one curve consisting of the product of four circles on the global product of four Riemann spheres. With time dimension, $i \alpha$, in the current universe, charted to only imaginary and the other dimensions to the real.

So globally, in this topology, we have this closed timelike curve, which is the only curve.

Am I right about the conclusions?

So my question is that what are the implications, especially the in terms of the insights related to the global topology of the universe, if we note that the theory of relativity is not a pictorial representation as highlighted by Niels Bohr.

Comment: The four-fold product of the Riemann sphere is an 8-manifold over $\mathbb{R}$, and thus not a 4D spacetime. And by saying that a theory is not "literal" because $\mathrm{i}^2 = -1$ involves the imaginary unit, *any* theory where a damn *minus* occurs would not be "literal", would it?

Comment: The product of four circles on four spheres is a 4D spacetime, isn't it? About the minus I like to presume that it is imaginary as suggested by Bohr and then work out the geometrical implications here.

Comment: The Riemann sphere is the one-point compactification of the plane, i.e. a compact 2-manifold over $\mathbb{R}$. Its fourfold product is an 8-manifold over $\mathbb{R}$. Our spacetime is (presumed to) be a 4-manifold over $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, this is not a spacetime. Also, I really don't understand Bohr's argument, I think it is nonsense. The Minkowski metric can simply be given as an inner product on the tangent spaces induced by the matrix $\mathrm{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$, no $\mathrm{i}$ involved and none appearing.

Comment: From Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy : "Neither does the theory of relativity, Bohr argued, provide us with a literal representation, since the velocity of light is introduced with a factor of i in the definition of the fourth coordinate in a four-dimensional manifold."

Comment: I assert that Bohr had no idea how differential geometry works *and/or* had misunderstood [Wick rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation). The latter part of that sentence is just nonsense.

Comment: People stopped using the explicit $i$ in relativity at sometime like the '50s.  We no longer really think of time as being an imaginary quantity, except when doing specialized things like Wick rotation.

Comment: Bohr, at various times, believed all kinds of things that we would today consider silly. For example, he thought that atoms should be quantized but light should not. The content of the question appears to be an attempt to take some outdated, wrong idea of Bohr's and expand it in some ill-defined way to produce a personal theory. I'm voting to close as off-topic, since we don't deal with personal theories here.

Comment: I got the answer here. Wick rotation provides the background that I didn't know about when reading the historical piece on Bohr arguments.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: People *should* have stopped using $i$ in relativity in 1916, since it doesn't work in GR. But some people still use 98-year-old ideas today, so an answer is providable here. (That answer being essentially "there is nothing good that comes from using $i$, and it doesn't even work in general.") Thus I voted (with no strong feelings) to keep open.